# Ошибка ClaimsPrincipal при использовании свойства в контроллере

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Использую asp.net core. Есть один контроллер и post метод, а также 3 класса(User, Account, Money transfer).
User cодержит статическое свойство Account, а Account List < MoneyTransfer>.
При попытке получить User.Account.MoneyTransfersList = new List < MoneyTransfer>(); в контроллере получаю ошибку:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'ClaimsPrincipal' does not contain a definition for 'Account' and no accessible extension method 'Account' accepting a first argument of type 'ClaimsPrincipal' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Privat24 65 Active.
```

Но если попытаться создать в методе любого класса , то проблем не будет. Гугл указал на проблемы с аутентификацией , но у меня ее нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а как Вы инициализируете сам Account в User?

Comment: Статическое свойство к классе User public static Account Account { get; set; } , поскольку аккаунт мне нужен только один . Если делать не статическим user.Account.MoneyTransfersList  = new List<MoneyTransfer>(); , то будет создаваться новый объект , а это не то что мне нужно

Comment: а можно больше кода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дайте Вашему классу User другое имя.

Ваша проблема состоит в том, что Ваш контроллер наследует ControllerBase:

```
public class имя Вашего котроллера : ControllerBase
```

и этот класс имеет свойство:

```
 public ClaimsPrincipal User { get; }
```

которое не знает абсолютно ничего про Ваш Account.

[официальная дока](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Вы чертовски правы! Как раз сегодня узнал в чем беда)

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли  указать ссылку на сборку  или using

Comment: пробовал устанавливать Nuget пакет System.Security.Claims , пробовал добивать using System.Security.Claims; В Dependencies ссылка есть. Пока ничего не помогло

Comment: Попробуйте поменять User.Account.MoneyTransfersList = new List();  на User.Account.MoneyTransfersList = new List<MoneyTransfers>();

Comment: пробовал , та же ошибка. Как временное решение сделал: static List<MoneyTransfer> list = new List<MoneyTransfer>(); Но это не то что нужно